# If a non-Jew wears a kippah at the Kotel, does it imply that he believes in G-d?

Tags: gentiles

Shalom brothers and sisters (I believe that all humans are siblings). I'm an agnostic non-Jew who will be visiting the Kotel. I want to use a kippah there if it is only to show respect for people. But I found that Rabbi Bradley Shavit Artson says that non-Jews should wear kippot (for example in synagogues) "as a sign of humility in the presence of" G-d ("Jewish answers to real-life questions", p. 24). I know that non-Jews have used kippot at the Kotel (for example, American presidents). But most of them (at least) were theists. So my question is whether or not the use of a kippah will imply in any way that I am a theist (I don't want to "lie" in this regard). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106911/discussion-on-question-by-philosopher-of-science-if-a-non-jew-wears-a-kippah-at).

Comment: You question is whether one thing "will imply" another. Please clarify with an [edit] to the question what sort of implication you're asking about (for example, an implication in the opinion of onlookers, or an implication according to the rules of Judaism (halakha), or what).

Comment: Do you use the abbreviation "AD" when discussing the date?

Comment: What date are you talking about?

Comment: Whilst a kippa does have the purpose of "as a sign of humility in the presence of G-d", wearing one at the Kotel is merely a courtesy to Jews there and doesn't say anything about your religious beliefs. Jews are well aware that many people visiting do not share all/some of our beliefs.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Both Spinoza and Rambam (in some ways) were deists and theists. Personally, I see no value in being an agnostic. But my guess is that its better than atheism. I'd be interested to learn why you are an agnostic and not a theist.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience the secular date. If Anno Domini stands for "year of our lord" are you, by using it, implying a belief in a lord? What about using currency that has "In God We Trust" on it?

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Based on what everyone else says, I think it is fine to wear a kippah. The Pope dons one.

Comment: Don't non-Jews have their own skull caps when they wear zucchettos and pileolus anyway?

Comment: Dear @Turk Hill What Popes wear is not a kippah. It is called a zucchetto, as you well said. I don't use the expression "AD", but the expression "CE" (Common Era), which is current in academia. I don't think this is the best place to discuss why I am an agnostic, but we could take the chat somewhere else if you would like that. Best regards.

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Yes, I would be interested in chatting with you. You can reach me at turkt082@gmail.com

Comment: @Philosopherofscience Are you still interested in telling me why you are agnostic? I would like to know.